# Build failure - Maven ,how to run maven project outside eclipse

Tags: maven

i am using 
D:\project\adaptor>mvn clean install -DskipTests
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.
3.2:compile (default-compile) on project adaptor: Compilation failure:

unable to create jar file inside .m2 repository

Comment: Full log output and not only excerpts...

Comment: "Compilation failure" means there's a problem with Java syntax in at least one of your source files, or maven doesn't have all necessary dependencies. Probably, when you run it from Eclipse, it uses some additional classpath for resolving dependencies.